# Update statement is too slow with Correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, correlated-subquery

I am using below update statement and it is way too slow(it takes around 10-12 seconds)

```
UPDATE temp_final t
   SET name = (
        SELECT DISTINCT(nm.name)
          FROM table_name nm,
               temp_final fn
         WHERE nm.id       = fn.senid
           AND fn.senid    = t.senid
           AND fn.rowgroup = t.rowgroup
           AND fn.mid      = t.mid
           AND fn.sid      = t.sid
           AND fn.pid      = t.pid
           AND fn.reid     = t.reid
           AND fn.retype   = t.retype
        )
 WHERE t.reid   = n_reid
   AND t.retype = n_retype
   AND t.sid    = c_sid
   AND t.pid    = n_pid;
```

Columns of temp_final table are not indexed , as this table includes lot of data update. I think , I cannot convert correlated subquery to join as it is using distinct clause.Plan of this query gives below result:

```
OPERATION                              OBJECT        CARDINALITY     COST
- UPDATE STATEMENT                                       1925        337046      
  - UPDATE                             temp_final 
    -TABLE ACCESS(FULL)                temp_final        1925        171
      - Filter Predicates
        - AND
          -T.SID='123'
          -T.PID=21
          -T.REID=9
          -T.RETYPE=1
    -SORT(UNIQUE)                                         1          175
      - NESTED LOOPS                                      1          174 
         -TABLE ACCESS(BY INDEX ROWID)  TABLE_NAME        1           2
           -INDEX(UNIQUE SCAN)          NAME_PK           1           1  
             -ACCESS PREDICATES
               NM.ID=:B1
         -TABLE ACCESS(FULL)            temp_final        1           172
           - Filter Predicates
             - AND
               -fn.mid=:B1
               -fn.senid=:B2
               -fn.sid =:B3
               -fn.rowgroup =:B4
               -fn.pid=:B5
               -fn.reid=:B6
               -fn.retype=:B7
               -nm.id = fn.senid
```

Table temp_final contains around 8k records and table table_name contains around 2 lac records

Please let me know how could i improve performance of this query?

Regards

Comment: Is fn.SenId a unique key for the temp_final table. Also is the combination of name and id unique in table_name?

Comment: Hello Vishad, fn.SenId is not a unique key for the temp_final table and Since id is a primary key for table_name so id and name is unique combination always. but how wud it help in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your self join. Isn't this statement sufficient:

```
UPDATE temp_final t
   SET name = (
        SELECT nm.name
          FROM table_name nm
         WHERE nm.id       = t.senid
        )
 WHERE t.reid   = n_reid
   AND t.retype = n_retype
   AND t.sid    = c_sid
   AND t.pid    = n_pid;
```

Comment: Hello , thanks for your response. It is a legacy system and original query has distinct also. if subquery return more than one row , it will fail.Though I have tested your query with one set of test data and it updates same number of row as original query.

Comment: You don't need the `DISTINCT` if id is the primary key of table_name. Is the smaller version any faster than the original version?

Comment: yes , it is faster.I will test smaller query with 10-15 more test sets to be on safer side and accept your answer. Thanks a lot. @wolφi , i have a very huge procedure whose performance is very poor and i need to improve it, would you recommend any book or material. Please note , I have not worked much on database side.Thanks.

Comment: I learned most from Tom Kyte's two books about  [architecture](https://www.amazon.com/Expert-Oracle-Database-Architecture-Programming/dp/1430229462) and [design](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Oracle-Design-Osborne-ORACLE/dp/0072230657). The [Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-A42A6EF0-20F8-4F4B-AFF7-09C100AE581E) is really excellent, worth reading cover to cover (and nobody else does, so you'll have an advantage :-)

Comment: Thanks  wolφi for your suggestion , I will check this out.